# why the java generic type is a must when I implement Interator<E>

Tags: java

I wrote this piece of code, and it works fine. but I have a question:

why it should be `public class PeekingIterator<E> implements Iterator<E>`, not
`public class PeekingIterator implements Iterator<E>`. I ask this because if I replace E with Integer in the code, it will work. I mean `public class PeekingIterator implements Iterator<Integer>` is correct.

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class PeekingIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {

    private E nextElem;
    private boolean hasNextElem;
    private Iterator<E> iter;

    public PeekingIterator(Iterator<E> iterator) {
        iter = iterator;
        nextElem = next();
        hasNextElem = true;

    }

    public E peek() {
        return nextElem;
    }

    @Override
    public E next() {
        if (!hasNextElem) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        E res = nextElem;
        if (hasNext()) {
            nextElem = iter.next();
            hasNextElem = true;
        } else {
            hasNextElem = false;
        }
        return res;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return hasNextElem;
    }

}
```

Comment: If it were `class PeekingIterator implements Iterator<E>`, `E` is not defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`E` is an identifier. If you say that `class PeekingIterator<E> implements Iterator<E>`, the compiler knows that this identifier is a generic type parameter.

This allows you to instantiate `PeekingIterator` as:

```
PeekingIterator<Integer> it1 = new PeekingIterator<>();
```

or

```
PeekingIterator<String> it2 = new PeekingIterator<>();
```

i.e. your `PeekingIterator` class can iterate over any type of elements.

If you declare `PeekingIterator` as `class PeekingIterator implements Iterator<E>`, the compiler searches for some type (class or interface) named `E`. If it doesn't find it, that's a compilation error.

If you declare `class PeekingIterator implements Iterator<Integer>`, this works, since `Integer` is a class. This limits your `PeekingIterator` to always iterate over `Integer` elements.